# Quoting items when using implode function

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to use the `implode` function on array; and its working fine and i am returning result fine as it should suppose to do.  I would now like to add extra quotation marks at the start and end of each item.

EG: I am currently getting this result in implode:

```
jan,feb,march,april,etc,etc
```

Instead I would like each item to be quoted:

```
"jan","feb","march","april","etc","etc"
```

Here is little code how i am using to implode something from my array

```
$selectedMonths = implode(",",array_column($selectedMonths,'id'));
```

As it is already string, I tried this below code also, but it was of no use. as it is already a string, but when imploding the commas are not added.

```
foreach($selectedMonths as $value){
    array_replace($selectedMonths,array_map('strval', array_slice($value, 0)));
}
```

Initially I am getting `$selectedMonths` as a json array, for which i have used `json_decode()` in php and in that `foreach` I have tried after converting the json array to associated array.  But now how to add extra `""` around every comma separated value?

Comment: $array = array("jan", "feb", "march", "april");
$selectedMonths = implode("','", $array);
Kinda works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $array = array("jan", "feb", "march", "april", "etc", "etc");
    echo '"' . implode('","', $array) . '"';

?>
```

Output:

```
"jan","feb","march","april","etc","etc"
```

Comment: Thankyou sir, this was a simple trick.. I didn't knew we can concatanate extra quotes from outside of the function.. 
Many Thanks, Problem Solved..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do, is get a JSON string from your array? For that you can use `json_encode`:

```
$json = json_encode($array);
```

But to append and prepend a quote mark to every string in an array, you can use `array_map`:

```
$array = ["jan","feb","march","april","etc","etc"];
$mapped = array_map($array, function($value) {
    return '"' . $value . '"';
});
```